# Is there a way to create a partial regression plot in Python?

Tags: python, statmodels

I have a question regarding the `statmodels graphic` module.

Let's assume I have built a linear regression with an interaction term:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf    
reg = smf.ols(data=data, 
              formula= "y ~ age + C(group, Treatment('a')) + C(gender, Treatment('female')) + weight_del6_relative * pc1")
```

Now, my goal is to plot a partial regression based on this linear regression for the interaction term.

Is there a way to do so using `statsmodels.graphics`?
So far, I have encountered two issues:

- Using [plot_partregress](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.regressionplots.plot_partregress.html#statsmodels.graphics.regressionplots.plot_partregress) does not allow for a regression fit (`reg.fit()`) as an input, and there is no option (or at least I didn't succeed) to specify interaction terms or reference levels for categorical variables.
- Using [plot_regress_exog](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.regressionplots.plot_regress_exog.html#statsmodels.graphics.regressionplots.plot_regress_exog) or [plot_partregress_grid](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.regressionplots.plot_partregress_grid.html#statsmodels.graphics.regressionplots.plot_partregress_grid) give the desired output of a partial regression for the exog of interest, but returns a figure in which the desired plot is a subplot. so far, I haven't been able to access only the partial regression

Thanks!